# Cat eating with paws and then flings it EVERYWHERE

Tags: cats, behavior, feeding, eating

My cat loves his wet food. He can't have dry because he has so few teeth from a genetic mouth disorder, lucky us. So after ruining one of my walls, because when he is done eating he flings his paws so hard to shake out any excess food which stick to the wall... so then I thought if I put his food in one of those covered kitty litter boxes, problem solved. That worked briefly and now he backs out of the box after eating, so he can lick his paws and again fling the remnants everywhere. Ugg, what can I do here? Anybody else have one of these kitties and what did you do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Try using a different dish to feed him.**

One of the common reasons cats will eat with their paws is that they don't like putting their face in the dish their meal is being served in. It's theorized that they don't like the feeling of their whiskers touching the sides of the dish.  Or it could be that the cat finds it difficult to eat around the corners of bowls, and it's much easier to use its paws to get the food that way. Therefore, most pet food bowls aren't actually very good for feeding your cat with. Look instead for very shallow bowls that have no corners to them. Or even just use plates instead.

**Try to clean your cat's paws for him.**

You could also try to monitor your cat during meals, and then clean his paws when he appears done, to intercept him before he starts flinging food.

**If all else fails, protect your wall.**

I'm sure there's endless ways to simply protect your walls from catfood. You could try for instance, attaching one of those kid's placemats to your wall with some easy to remove adhesive.